# USB disk not auto-mounting in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, automount

It used to, but suddenly now it doesn't. The device shows up in the following:

```
dmesg | tail -1
[394191.758315] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
```

...which I know is the correct device because:

```
lsusb | tail -1
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 1058:1021 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 2TB
```

identifies device 9 as the USB drive in question. This is what `fdisk -l` gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8c949010

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      616447      307200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          616448   332125058   165754305+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       620943360   625127423     2092032    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda4       332126206   620943359   144408577    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       332126208   609130495   138502144   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       609132544   620943359     5905408   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

**The device does not show up in /media.** Also, it auto-detects and works fine in Windows. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I never figured this out. In the end, I just did a clean install of 14.04 and it's not an issue for me now.